# Django Admin autocomplete field selector unidesirable behavior

Tags: python, django, templates, autocomplete, admin

I have an enterprise project based in Django which is stuck in version 3.1.7 due to unexpected behavior of autocomplete field admin selector.

In former versions, when you click in the combobox (Foreign key selector), the text input editor is autofocused, so once you click the title you can automatically start writing for searching in the list of fereign key values.

I tried to update to newer version of Django, but certain users have complained that now they have to make the extra step of clicking in the text input editor, because it does no longer automatically write once you click the combobox/selector title (the text editor is not automatically focused).

Ever if this is a minor nuance for computer versed users, workshop users (who lest's be honest, many of them are quite dumb with tech stuff) complain because it does not longer does the usual "easier" stuff and have to be more careful.

Anyway, I do not understand why the change of this behavior in newer versions, it is a loss even if it is a small one.

Is there any way to force the admin template component to work as it preivously did?

**---Edit--**

A picture so the issue is better understood:

[image: Example of autosearch in autocomplete field]

Categoría is a marked as autocomplete field in Django admin. When the user clicks in the title of the selector, cursor is automatically set in the text editor (where lowerecase "gam" in written in the picture), so users can directly search as soon as the selector is clicked. This happens for Django<4, but for Django>=4, the text editor is not directly focused when the selector is clicked, so users have to click it before writting a filter pattern.

Comment: Is it perhaps possible to use an image, it is not really clear to me what is happening?

Comment: That's a good recommendation. I have added a picture of an example, hope it is better understood now.